# How to add autoprefixer with vite + react project

Tags: reactjs, vite, postcss, autoprefixer

Hi I created the react app using `npm create vite` and I tried to integrate `autoprefixer` but it's not working.

`vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [autoprefixer()],
        },
    },
});
```

`package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [ "last 2 versions", "not dead" ]
```

I tried creating a `postcss.config.js` and it didn't worked either.

`postcss.config.js`

```
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

export const plugins = {
    plugins: [autoprefixer()],
};
```

Would be great if anyone can help me!

Comment: Can you say which node version you are on ?

Comment: @flydev node: v18.7.0, npm: 8.15.0

Answer (score 9):

Vite appears to use `postcss-load-config` for its configuration.

> If the project contains valid PostCSS config (any format supported by
> postcss load-config, e.g. postcss.config.js), it will be automatically
> applied to all imported CSS. https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#postcss

I solved this with `.postcssrc.json` and a `browserslist` root key in `package.json`.

First install autoprefixer `npm install -D autoprefixer`

`postcss` and `postcss-load-config` are included with vite

No additional config needed in  `vite.config.js`, just the default:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
});
```

`.postcssrc.json`

```
{
  "map": true,
  "plugins": {
    "autoprefixer": {}
  }
}
```

Set up browserslist with one of the [recommended options](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#best-practices)

`package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ]
}
```

Result:

`index.css`

```
:root {
 ...
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
:root {
  ...
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: took 2 hrs to figure this browserslist thing

Comment: Why is the browserList defaults necessary?